# How can I return all School Names?

Tags: collegescorecard

Per_page max 100, I want all pages, and not have to request page by page.  Can I get all pages, provide string of pages?  Seems like basics request.

Comment: Could Wikidata be an option (despite your "collegescoreboard"-tag)? Or does it necessarily have to be Collegescoreboard?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving all school names in a single request or requesting multiple pages at once is not currently supported.  The only available option is to paginate through each return with the currently implemented size limit.

Some possible workarounds:

- Script the request pagination process in the programming language of your choice.  Cache the results for future use.
- Leverage the raw data files used to power the API: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/